# How to get a full path of web page to my views.py?

Tags: django

How to get a full path of web page to my views.py?

http://192.168.0.178:8000/customers-orders/37/customers-orders-date/?datefilter=06%2F14%2F2020+-+06%2F26%2F2020

How to get this path to my views.py for to work with it?

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#:~:text=Quick%20overview,argument%20to%20the%20view%20function

> > > request.build_absolute_uri()

That's all